# Button not adding entry into list item

Tags: javascript, html

Perhaps I'm missing something simple here..
The 'Add' button is not triggering the item to be added to the li.
The Launch Task button is not important at the moment.

Thanks!

```
function add() {
var a = document.getElementById("input_txt").value;
var b = document.getElementById("items");

var tag = document.createElement("li");
tag.innerHTML = a;

b.append(tag);

document.getElementById("input_txt").value = "";
```

}

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <title>TaR</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="styelsheet" />

<body>
        <div>
            <section>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item" id="input_txt" />
                    <button onclick="add(0" id="add_txt">Add</button>
            </section>


            <ul id="items">


            </ul>
            <section>
                    <button onclick="Launch(0" id="launch_task">Launch Task</button>
            </section>
        </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well your code has a typo.... atually 2.... Is that your actual code? Learn to use your console.

Comment: there us a typo, `<button onclick="add()" id="add_txt">Add</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parenthesis:

```
 <button onclick="add(0" id="add_txt">Add</button>


 <button onclick="Launch(0" id="launch_task">Launch Task</button>
```

**From**

```
add(0
Launch(0
```

**To**

```
add(0)
Launch(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo, see `<button onclick="add(0" id="add_txt">Add</button>` missing ) and should be `<button onclick="add(0)" id="add_txt">Add</button>`

However it's better to setup event listener programmatically.

In your script add:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function() {
    document.getElementById('add_txt').addEventListener('click', add);
});
```